# How to use AsyncStorage.setItem in fetch callback?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I got syntax error in my code.

```
  async getJSON() {
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((responseText) => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, responseText);        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
      });
  },
```

Error is Unexpected token on `await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, responseText);`
I guess it's complaining `await`

Comment: add the async modifier

Comment: Why are you still using `then`/`catch` and callbacks when you have `async`/`await`???

Comment: @Bergi I added them when I got syntax error for that ``await AsyncStorage.setItem``. Didn't know the ``async`` should be added to that callback function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every await you need an async.

```
 async getJSON() {
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then(async (responseText) => { // <-- add async here
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, responseText);        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
      });
  },
```

Also... the point of async/await is to make the code look sync when is actually async. You can rewrite the above code like this:

```
async getJSON() {
    try {
      var response = await fetch(url);
      var responseText = response.text();
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, responseText);
    } catch(error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.